# Iterate Over a list, deleting every value that matches a database

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have been working on this function in python. I intend for it to iterate over a list of phone numbers, checking with a database to see whether the number has been used yet or not. If it has been used, it should remove the phone number from the list and choose another and check the new one until an unused one has been found and return the unused one. If it has not been used, it should simply just return the number. However, after one run, it picks a number, checks it, runs, and then enters it into the database. The next run deletes the previously used number, and picks another that hasn't been used. It continues to run and enters this number into the database. The third run does not delete the previously used number from the list, but it still picks a new one regardless. Although this still works, when the numbers run out, since there are no others to pick, it continues using the last number in the list for every following run of the script. Sorry if the code is a bit sloppy right now, I am in a bit of a rush and this is only a script I have been messing around with. I hope this is clear, and not too confusing. If I need to clear any confusion, I will be glad too.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that these phone numbers are constantly grabbed from a website by another script. These set of numbers listed below is just a dummy set for testing. So in the end, I am needing to see if these recently grabbed numbers have been used by checking with the database tables.

```
import random
import names




##############################Information Variables##################################
emailAddress = "Fakeemail@mail.com"
titleValues = [0,1] #0 is 'Mr.', 1 is 'Mrs.'




country = 'Schwifty'
title = random.choice(titleValues)


#Generate a random name based on gender
if title == 1:
    firstName = names.get_first_name(gender= 'female')
else:
    firstName = names.get_first_name(gender= 'male')

lastName =  names.get_last_name()

fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName

print(fullName)



phoneNumber = '111-222-3333'



#########################################################



import sqlite3
import time
import datetime


conn = sqlite3.connect('accounts.db')
c = conn.cursor()





def createTable():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts(Email TEXT, Name TEXT, Title TEXT, PhoneNumber TEXT, Country TEXT, DateStamp TEXT)')

def dynamic_data_entry(email, name, title, phone, country):
    unix = time.time()
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp  (unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO accounts (Email, Name, Title, PhoneNumber, Country, DateStamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (email, name, title, phone, country, date))

    conn.commit()

createTable()




#################################TEST NUMBER CHECK###########################
phoneNumbers = ['111-222-3333', '444-555-6666', '777-888-9999', '123-456-7890', '321-321-321']
def checkNumber(a):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE PhoneNumber = ?", (a,))
    row = c.fetchall()
    if row:
        print("Phone number has already been used, choosing another and deleting current from list.")
        phoneNumbers.remove(a)
        a = random.choice(phoneNumbers)
        checkNumber(a)
    elif row == False:
        print("Number is fresh and new, using " + a)
        return a
    elif row == None:
        print('No new phone numbers to use, exiting... ')
        exit()


# for num in phoneNumbers:
#   checkNumber(num)
#   print(num)
checkNumber(phoneNumber)
print(phoneNumbers)
print('working')

##########################################
#        INSERT DATA TO DB               #
##########################################





#Insert information to database in this order: email, name, title, phone, country
dynamic_data_entry(emailAddress, fullName, title, phoneNumber, country)

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t do this. Populate a table with your phone numbers and update each phone number record with a field like ‘used’ once used.

Always keep state and data modeling in the database where possible. It is made for it.

Update in response to OP:

Create a separate table for phone numbers and replace your number field in the accounts table with a foreign key id to the primary key of the phone number table. This is called maintaining an object model or data model, so that if you want to query accounts, you have the data you need via foreign key, and if you just want phone numbers you can query the phone numbers table directly.

This way your phone number ‘objects’ can have their own attributes like ‘already called’ or ‘on do not call list’ without muddying up your accounts ‘object’.

If you want to insert a new account, you should first insert your new phone number 'object' into the phone number table and return the id, and then use that in your account insert.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you think that creating another separate table to log the numbers in would be the best choice then? This way I can still keep each number that is associated with a name in the original database together. So one db, keeping personal information together (name, email, country, and phone associated to that name), and the other db, keeping track of what numbers have been used and which ones have not?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, which I will now be editing the post, that these numbers are frequently grabbed from a website, so they are constantly changing, thus the reason that I store these in a database and I need them to be checked to see if they have already been used. What would be the most efficient way to check if the recently grabbed numbers in the script have been used or not using the database?

Comment: Okay thank you so much! And especially for the fast reply... This has given me quite a bit of more insight on the situation, and I should be able to continue from here.